# How to disable insert block button and not allow add any block in 'InnerBlocks'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating a custom gutenberg block,but i want to disable or remove insert block button on top and bottom of block.
Also,i want to not allow add more block in  by click button add.

I'm working on WordPress 5.2.3

```
<InnerBlocks
    template={ [ 'item' ] }
    templateLock={ false }
    allowedBlocks={ false }
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your **block template** with the InnerBlocks you want in the respective order (and with possible placeholders, nested blocks...) – as a multidimensional array. And put this right below your component imports at the top of the block file.

`const TEMPLATE = [
    ['foo/block1', {}, []],
    ['foo/block2', {}, []],
]`

In your **edit function** use

`<InnerBlocks 
    template={TEMPLATE} 
    templateLock="all" 
/>`

- `"all"` locks the template completely, no blocks can be added,
  removed or re-ordered
- `"false"` template is not locked
- `"insert"` blocks can only be re-ordered

As you don’t want any blocks to be added you can omit `allowedBlocks`. This would only be necessary to allow certain blocks to be added (in combination with `templateLock="false"`)